# The procedure entry point could not be located in the dynamic link library

Tags: visual-c++

I'm trying to proxy ddraw.dll for a game I'm working on (Not for cheating purposes), There are two functions called by the main game in order for it to start:

DirectDrawEnumerateExA

DirectDrawCreateEx

I've added both of these to my C++ project plus done countless amount of research online and I've have got nowhere so far, I've tried various tutorials and various methods such as using a  .def file, I can't seem to figure out what is wrong.

When launching the game I get "The procedure entry point DirectDrawEnumerateExA could not be located in the dynamic link library DDRAW.dll"

Here is the code base I'm currently using:

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <ddraw.h>

typedef HRESULT (WINAPI* DirectDrawEnumerateExA_td)(LPDDENUMCALLBACKEXA lpCallback, LPVOID lpContext, DWORD dwFlags);
typedef HRESULT (WINAPI* DirectDrawCreateEx_td)(GUID FAR *lpGuid, LPVOID *lplpDD, REFIID iid, IUnknown FAR *pUnkouter);

static struct
{
    HMODULE hGameDLL;
    char* pGameDLL;

    // entry points
    DirectDrawEnumerateExA_td OldDirectDrawEnumerateExA;
    DirectDrawCreateEx_td OldDirectDrawCreateEx;

} g_state;

extern "C" HRESULT __declspec(dllexport) OldDirectDrawEnumerateExA(LPDDENUMCALLBACKEXA lpCallback, LPVOID lpContext, DWORD dwFlags)
{
    return g_state.OldDirectDrawEnumerateExA(lpCallback, lpContext, dwFlags);
}

extern "C" HRESULT __declspec(dllexport) WINAPI OldDirectDrawCreateEx(GUID FAR *lpGuid, LPVOID *lplpDD, REFIID iid, IUnknown FAR *pUnkouter)
{
    return g_state.OldDirectDrawCreateEx(lpGuid, lplpDD, iid, pUnkouter);
}

BOOL WINAPI DllMain(HINSTANCE hinstDLL, DWORD fdwReason, LPVOID lpvReserved)
{
    if(fdwReason == DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH)
    {
            char infoBuf[MAX_PATH];
            GetSystemDirectory(infoBuf, MAX_PATH);
            strcat_s(infoBuf, MAX_PATH, "\\ddraw.dll");

            g_state.hGameDLL = LoadLibrary(infoBuf); 
            g_state.pGameDLL = (char*)g_state.hGameDLL;

            if(!g_state.hGameDLL)
            {
                MessageBox(NULL, "Unable to load ddraw.dll", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
                ExitProcess(0);
            }

            g_state.OldDirectDrawEnumerateExA = (DirectDrawEnumerateExA_td)GetProcAddress(g_state.hGameDLL, "DirectDrawEnumerateExA");

            if(!g_state.OldDirectDrawEnumerateExA)
            {
                MessageBox(NULL, "Unable to find entry point: DirectDrawEnumerateExA", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
                ExitProcess(0);
            }

            g_state.OldDirectDrawCreateEx = (DirectDrawCreateEx_td)GetProcAddress(g_state.hGameDLL, "DirectDrawCreateEx");

            if(!g_state.OldDirectDrawCreateEx)
            {
                MessageBox(NULL, "Unable to find entry point: DirectDrawCreateEX", "Error", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
            }

            MessageBox(NULL, "Test.", "Test Box", MB_OK | MB_ICONEXCLAMATION);
    }
    else if(fdwReason == DLL_PROCESS_DETACH)
    {
        if (g_state.hGameDLL)
        {
            FreeLibrary(g_state.hGameDLL);
        }
    }

    return TRUE;
}
```

Comment: Well, the message looks appropriate.  You indeed did *not* implement those functions.

Answer (score 0):

One big issue is the call to LoaLibrary when DLL_PROCESS_ATTACH is taking place. Never do that! Instead, take a look at [the Best Practices for Creating DLLs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/gg487379.aspx) and correct this. The failure you are experimenting has to do with the side effect of calling LoadLibrary when the Loader has not yet finished to attach the DLL to the process.

Comment: Ahh, I did have it in the first __declspec functions before, But I was having the same problem

Comment: Of course, thanks Hans! You declared but forgot to implement the functions you overwrites.

Comment: Ah thanks, Could you point me in the right direction for that? I'm fairly new to C++

Comment: static struct { HMODULE hGameDLL; char* pGameDLL; // entry points DirectDrawEnumerateExA_td OldDirectDrawEnumerateExA{} DirectDrawCreateEx_td OldDirectDrawCreateEx{} } g_state;

Comment: Just provide a (dummy or not) body for the function declared, either inside or outside the class, struct.

Comment: I've added the code you suggested, However VC++ 2010 compiler is throwing out various errors: http://pastebin.com/wfzGA7jU

Comment: As a matter of fact, the errors are different than the original ones! My suggestion was just a quick and dirty example, showing you that the functions bodies were missing! now you need to set the expected content, semi-coloumns, syntax, etc.

Comment: I found where I was going wrong. I was naming it Oldxxx etc. When I checked the export table in PeID. Many thanks for your input Mox :)